# onCreate not called when screen rotates - Android

Tags: android, orientation, rotation

I am building an app that needs to know whether the device is in landscape or portrait mode. So I figured, I will use onCreate, I know that is called on device rotation. But onCreate is call only once!! When I rotate the device, nothing happens. I am debugging on an actual device, Motorola Xoom, so I am NOT using the emulator. Someone had this kind of problem?

Comment: Do you have `android:configChanges` tag for the activity in your manifest?

Comment: I have it, it is like this: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Comment: Then @blackbelt's answer is for you :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check if int the Manifest file you declare

> android:configChanges="orientation"

if you declared this flag, the activity will not be destroyed and recreated and the callback

```
onConfigurationChanged()
```

will be called.

Comment: I could not accept it sooner, because I do not have the reputation to accept two answers in a short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

For target API > 13
you need to declare both `orientation|screenSize` for your `Activity` to make `onCreate` not call

```
<activity 
    ...
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    />
```

If you only define `orientation` or `screenSize`, `onCreate` still call.
Chekc it here [activity-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) -> android:configChanges -> "orientation"